# Could this code potentially result in an infinite loop?

Tags: java, string, infinite-loop

Is there any value that could be assigned to the `myString` variable that would result in an infinite loop in the code below?

```
while (true) {
    if (myString.indexOf("  ") == -1) {
        break;
    }
    myString = myString.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```

Comment: Is this a single-threaded environment?

Comment: No, the code will always terminate. If `myString` is `null`, it will terminate with an exception, but you probably know that.

Comment: That looks like javascript...

Comment: what is the scope of `myString`?

Comment: @csmckelvey Are you sure? Give example?

Comment: @ManofSnow: No, JavaScript doesn't have `String#replaceAll`. Java does. Other than that, yeah, well, they're both languages syntactically derived from B, so...

Comment: Something tells me some of the OP's code IS already infinite-looping, hence the question.  ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He could add a function to prototype.

Comment: @ManofSnow: LOL True. But Occam's Razor tells us that it's Java (not least because it's tagged `java`).

Comment: @Tom nailed it -- it would terminate as long as no other threads are updating myString at the same time.

Comment: It's safe to assume that `myString` is of type `String`, presumably?  (http://ideone.com/CpyuoP)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If it is a trick question, and the answer is "yes", then `myString` being an instance of some weird `MyString` class is arguably the most natural explanation. Perhaps ex aequo with running in a multi-threaded environment, as @Tom noticed.

Comment: Of course you don't even need a loop at all, see my edited answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could this code potentially result in an infinite loop?

No. But if might throw an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if `myString` is `null`.

If the String doesn't contain two spaces, it'll `break;` after the first iteration. Otherwise, it does contain two spaces, and it replaces it with one space, then, it won't have two spaces again, and it'll `break;`.

Comment: @Aquillo I noticed that.. replaced it with words :)

Comment: Your last paragraph might be read to imply that the loop will only ever run once, which is not true; `replaceAll()` might actually *create* new instances of two adjacent spaces by replacing two adjacent double-space matches with single spaces. In this case the loop would run again and replace the newly-created double space, etc. But as long as the string is finite (a safe assumption) it will eventually terminate.

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't - however the loop could be much better structured:

```
while (myString.indexOf("  ") != -1) {
    myString = myString.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```

Sometimes you need break in a loop, but if you don't need it you should avoid it.

A better solution of course would be to not use a loop at all, remember that replaceAll works from regex:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
```

For example:

```
String str = "this is a   test      string with long     white space    chunks";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[ ]+", " "));
```

Try it here: http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52c19090e4b00bdc99e8a943

Comment: @user2336315 : no because it would handle the cases where there is a streak of more than 2 spaces

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, obvisoulsy you're right. You mean it _"wouldn't"_ right ?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no double space in your string, the condition

```
if(myString.indexOf("  ") == -1)
```

will be true, and the loop will break.

If there *is* a double space, the condition is false. You continue to the line

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("  ", " ");
```

which will replace all double strings with a single string. On the next pass, this means that the initial condition is true, and the loop will break. It's possible that a string with many consecutive spaces will need a few passes through the loop (each time `__` turns into `_`, but I don't believe that is recursive, so 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 space in three passes through the loop).

Comment: "If there is a double space, the condition is true".  No, if there is a double space, the expression is false (and the break isn't executed).

Comment: Ah yes, I see you correction. Will edit. Thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot loop infinitely.  The thing to watch out for, in similar cases, is that `indexOf` just searches for a sequence of characters that matches exactly, while `replaceAll` takes a regular expression.  Jon Skeet described a case that tripped him up because the two methods he used (one for searching and one for replacing) treated certain character combinations differently (I think it had to do with Unicode combining characters, I don't recall offhand), and ended up with an unexpected infinite loop.  In this case, there doesn't seem to be a problem.  I checked the documentation to see if there were any way a pattern-matching flag could be sneaked into the `replaceAll` and cause it to behave differently, but I don't think there is.

Since `replaceAll` takes regexes, though, you could accomplish the same thing without a loop:

```
myString.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
```

or

```
myString.replaceAll("  +", " ");
```

or other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't happen. You can prove this by induction on the string length.

Basically it comes down to the following observation:

`myString` becomes shorter in every iteration of the loop (replacement of a pattern that exists in the string with a string of shorter length) or the loop terminates.

Since you can't find a non-empty String in a String of length 0 and `myString.length()` is finite, the loop must clearly terminate after `myString.length()` (finitely many) iterations (Actually we could get a better bound, but for simplicity...).